# what does Xserver access control mean

Tags: security, x11, xorg, x-server, access-control

What meaning does Xserver access control have, when the Xserver is started with tcp disabled:

```
/usr/bin/X11/X -nolisten tcp
```

AFAIU, Xserver can be used to allow remote network connection. But, if it is used only locally, is the access control meaningless?

Do these access permissions only have meaning, when the Xserver is listening on public IP interface, i.e. `0.0.0.0`, as seen with `netstat -lptun` ?

Further, when I run `xhost`, I see following output:

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
```

Where do these settings come from? (I have not configured anything). Is there some config file in `/etc` that contains access control permissions?

Is there any security issue, when I run `Xephyr` on top of my `Xserver` as a a different user? Is this secure?

```
Xephyr -screen 1920x1054 :1 &
DISPLAY=:1 su - nobody -c 'startlxde'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
Grant another user on the local machine access to our X server. It’s pretty easy:

```
$ xhost +SI:localuser:anotheruser
localuser:anotheruser being added to access control list
```

Then your user must show up when you:

```
$ xhost
```

[Reference](http://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=896)

Answer (score 0):

Run Xephyr with option `-nolisten tcp`, otherwise it is accessable for everyone in your network, maybe even from outside.

Furthermore, use cookies with option `-auth cookiefile`. Try to run `DISPLAY=:0 xterm` in Xephyr to check whether you can access your primary display.

`xhost` is discouraged for access control, it only can allow, but not restrict access from others. xhost settings are non-persistent, I don't know any config file for it.

In your example, you run Xephyr as host user and only startlxde as a different user.